# How to change UI component on AWS amplify Authenticator ui-react

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using Amazon Cognito for my registration page with AWS Amplify.
Everything is up and running as expected but, my only issue now is how to override the CSS component.

I can modify from the console but when copy and paste on my style component the code does not work.

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to modify the order of the CTA at the bottom of the sign-in and sign-up page and try to get them to display in a column rather than inline but because Amazon is using 'slot' I am struggling to find the solution.

Does anyone experienced the same issue or could give me some tips about how to force the UI component and style as my client wants?
Thanks

Comment: What component(s) are you using?

Comment: AWS amplify sign-in / sign-up

Comment: [Customize UI components](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/customui/q/platform/js#create-your-own-ui)